# Formating my json for highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I have this json array returned from an API.

```
[
{
    "localTimestamp": 1383091200,
    "swell": {
        "absMinBreakingHeight": 3.255
    }
},
{
    "localTimestamp": 1383102000,
    "swell": {
        "absMinBreakingHeight": 2.968
    }
}
]
```

I need to get this to work with highcharts and I am totally lost.  The data comes from an external API.

Do I need to bring in the array and change it to fit highcharts, or point highcharts to the API's URL and adjust highchart's code to work with what they send out.

I have the sample code from Highcharts that I have been working with here:

html:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
           type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    var url =  "jsonp.php?callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url,  function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});



</script>

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>






<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/themes/gray.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my php code:

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/json"); 

$array = array(7,4,2,8,4,1,9,3,2,16,7,12);

echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($array) . ')';    

?>
```

I know the php is wrong (obviously) I just don't know how to format my json to talk to highcharts.  Thanks in advance
M

To be clear, I'm trying to get my data (top) into the php array (bottom) ina format that can be read by highcharts.

Comment: What does the `$_GET['callback']` and parentheses mean? Is this a function call? If yes, this is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), not [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). `"The response to a JSONP request is not JSON and is not parsed as JSON; the returned payload can be any arbitrary JavaScript expression, and it does not need to include any JSON at all."` See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more details and search for JSONP on that documentation-page.

Comment: Yes, this is the JSONP example from the highcharts website.  Should I be using something else to fetch data from another site?

Comment: I don't know that. As you are using jQuery, please refer to their documentation as linked above.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm going about this the wrong way.  all I need is the timestamp and breakingwaveheight, so how could I echo or print this in this format:     
 [

Comment: [
[timestamp,waveheight]
[timestamp,waveheight]
]

Comment: @user2883183 Yes, that's the correct format for Highcharts. Here is more information: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data and jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-arrays-datetime/

Comment: Awesome, so now I'm still lost on how to get [ [timestamp,waveheight] [timestamp,waveheight] ] out of the above JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform your data (from JSON) into correct format like array of object `[{x:timestamp,waveheight},{timestamp,waveheight]]` or array of arrays like

```
[[timestamp,waveheight],[timestamp,waveheight]]
```

Generally in highcharts you need to use x/y parameter instead of you custom names.